# Stats: Standard Deviation Question

Tags: statistics

A data set has a mean of 12 and a standard deviation of 2. If 5 is added to twice each data value, the new data set has?

Answer: a mean of 29 and a standard deviation of 4.

I am not sure how to arrive at the answer.

Comment: In the formula for the variance, replace each $x_i$ by $2x_i + 5$, and then simplify.

Comment: When you multiply every data value by the same number (in this case $2$), then the standard deviation gets multiplied by the absolute value of that number. When you add the same number to every data value, you do not alter the standard deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of data values.

It's given that $\mu_x = 12$ and $\sigma_x=2$.

For $1 \le i \le n$, let $y_i = 2x_i + 5$.

Then
\begin{align*}
\mu_y &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (2x_i + 5)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 2x_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n5\\[4pt]
&=2\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) + 5\\[4pt]
&=2\mu_x + 5\\[5pt]
&=2(12) + 5\\[5pt]
&=29
\end{align*}

and
\begin{align*}
\sigma_y^2&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\mu_y)^2\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n {\large{(}}(2x_i + 5)-29{\large{)}}^2\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (2x_i - 24)^2\\[4pt]
&=4\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - 12)^2\right)\\[4pt]
&=4\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu_x)^2\right)\\[4pt]
&=4\sigma_x^2
\end{align*}

It follows that $\sigma_y=2\sigma_x = 2(2) = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

There are general rules about how linear transformations of data
affect the sample mean and variance:

If $Y_i = aX_i + b$, where $a > 0,$ then
$\bar Y = a \bar X + b$ and $S_y^2 = a^2S_x^2.$

In your case, $a = 2$ and $b = 5.$ The detailed answer by @quasi (+1)
has shown you the results.

Here are some special cases that may help you understand intuitively
what is going on.

(a) Suppose you are planning to put new tiles on your kitchen floor
and determine that the floor area is 20 square yards. Then you get
to the tile store and find that they price tile by the square foot.
Since there are 9 square feet to the square yard, you multiply by $a = 9$
to get 180 square feet for your kitchen floor. And if you are given
average prices per square foot you would multiply by $a = 9$ to get
average prices per square yard. In this example $b = 0.$

(b) Suppose the average age of the students in your AP statistics
class is 17.2. You agree to have a class reunion in 10 years.
If everybody shows up, the average age of the people
at the reunion will be 27.2 years. Here $b = 10$ and $a = 1$.
The variance of your ages will not have changed.